# Is there a way to replace the current process with a new one in a cross-platform way in Rust?

Tags: linux, windows, unix, rust, cross-platform

Similar to the linux `execve(3)` syscall, I want to replace the current process with a new one in Rust, in a way that works on *both* Unix and Windows systems. I'm fine with using crates if necessary, although I would like to stay away from `unsafe`.

So far, the only thing I've found in the standard library is [`std::os::unix::process::CommandExt::exec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/process/trait.CommandExt.html#tymethod.exec), but this only works on Unix. Looking for crates, I found the [exec](https://crates.io/crates/exec) crate, but it doesn't appear to support Windows. However, [this open PR](https://github.com/faradayio/exec-rs/pull/4) mentions that it's possible to use the `wexecvp` syscall on Windows to achieve the same functionality, although it doesn't work on the Windows Runtime and only works on Win32. (That's good enough for me, though.) I'm at a dead-end on how to do this without breaking out `libc::wexecvp` and `unsafe`.

Is there a way to replace the current process with a new one in a cross-platform way in Rust?

Comment: The question can be rephrased as: does the [WIN32 API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/) provides a primitive like `exec`. I believe it does not, but you need to check by yourself. If such a facility does not exist on Windows, the rust library cannot provide it. The most portable thing is [system(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html). You should accept to code differently on Windows and on Linux. They are different operating systems. Read some [OS textbook](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a question that is independent of the programming language used, because it's about the process models of operating systems.

The answer is simply No.

The Windows process model doesn't work this way -- it's not a *nix.
Some things are fundamentally nonportable. So, you'll need to figure out what your functional requirement is (e.g. stdio handle inheritance, permissions, environment, etc.), and how to implement that on the other platform(s).

I can't get more specific because you'd need to provide more details on what "replace the current process by another one" means for your app You can always launch another program and quit, which naively sounds like the same thing :-).